# How to split a string into words and numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

I need to tokenize a string representing an item in inventory in javascript getting words and numbers, for example:

Given the string 'Plane Engine 50x60' the tokens should be ['Plane','Engine','50','x','60']

Given the string 'Car wheel 220v' the tokens should be ['Car','wheel','220','v']

The solution could be a RegExp or a Javascript Algorithm

All the items have that kind of names come has measures like 20x30 and others have electronic info such as 220v. The thing I need to do is split like the examples above.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @amy, could you please explain me what is wrong with my question? I'm not an expert creating questions and I want to learn since the questions I have usually give me bad reputation points. And I want to someday be able to answer questions. Regards.

Comment: Use: /[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/g.exec(yourstring). Now you will have an array with your tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split by groups of either numbers or letters and then filter out the empty strings or spaces.

```js
'Car wheel 220v'.split(/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)/).filter(token => (token.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/)))
```